# OpenCL global vs __global and kernel vs __kernel

Tags: opencl

This is more a question of semantics.

In XCode, __global and global are syntax highlighted the same.
__kernel and kernel are syntax highlighted the same.

What is the difference between __global vs global and __kernel vs kernel? Are they the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference.

By manual for [__global](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/global.html):

> The address space names without the __ prefix i.e. global, local, constant and private may be substituted for the corresponding address space names with the __ prefix.